# Extracting address and function call from objdump using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to wrap my head around regex but I'm still having problems. I have this output (from `objdump -D`):

```
 804869f:   e8 cc fe ff ff          call   8048570 <socket@plt>
 8048713:   e8 38 fe ff ff          call   8048550 <bind@plt>
 8048750:   e8 0b fe ff ff          call   8048560 <listen@plt>
```

I want to get the address at which the calls happen (first column) and the name of the function (ie: socket, bind, listen).

I've tried this:

```
match = re.match(r' (.*): (.*) <(.*)@plt>', line)
print match.group(1)
print match.group(3)
```

From what I understand, I would expect this to work. First group should be a string between the first space char and the colon, third group should be between the `<` and `@` chars. I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a non greedy match

`.*` eats all character, instead be specific if things are known in advance

A *better* patter could be framed like following :

```
st=re.match(r'\s+([0-9A-Fa-f]+):'    # Address starting with one or more space
            r'\s+.+?'                # Skip characters (non-greedy using ?)
            r'([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\s+'     # Address followed by space
            r'<(\S+)@plt>',          # function name, anything except space
            line)
```

Also always check if match was successful,

```
if st: # Use st or some different variable other then 'match' itself
   print st.group(1)
   print st.group(2)
   print st.group(3)
```

Comment: +1 Works like a charm, still not sure I understand why mine didn't work though.

Comment: @Juicy, see with `*.?`, but as said, if things are known in advance pattern should be formed accordingly, in your case the address is fixed and will _only_ contain digits or letter `a-f`, etc